# SDE with stationary Log-normal distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Is there a stochastic differential equation whose solution follows a stationary Log-normal distribution?

I was thinking in the geometric Brownian motion

$$dx = (\alpha x )dt + (\sigma x )db, \quad \alpha,\beta\in\Re$$

whose probability density function $f_{S_{t}}(s;\mu ,\sigma ,t)$ is a Log-normal distribution

$$f_{x_{t}}(x;\mu ,\sigma ,t)={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}}\,{\frac {1}{x\sigma {\sqrt {t}}}}\,\exp \left(-{\frac {\left(\ln x-\ln x_{0}-\left(\mu -{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}\right)t\right)^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}t}}\right)$$.

But it depends on time (it is not stationary). Is there a simple SDE with stationary Log-normal distribution?

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(x)$ be an arbitrary time-independent CDF and $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion. The CDF of $B_t$ is
$\Phi(x/\sqrt{t})$ where $\Phi(x)$ is the standard normal CDF. Then
$$
U_t:=\Phi(B_t/\sqrt{t})
$$
is uniform on $[0,1]$ for all $t>0$ and
$$
X_t=F^{-1}(U_t)=F^{-1}\circ\Phi(B_t/\sqrt{t})
$$
is a stochastic process that has stationary distribution $F(x)\,.$ If $F^{-1}$ is $C^2$ Ito's formula is applicable and an SDE that is solved by $X_t$ is easily found:
$$\tag{1}
dX_t=f'(B_t)\,dB_t+\frac{1}{2}f''(B_t)\,dt
$$
where $f(x)=F^{-1}\circ \Phi(x/\sqrt{t})\,.$ Writing
$$
B_t=\sqrt{t}\,\Phi^{-1}(U_t)=\sqrt{t}\,\Phi^{-1}\circ F(X_t)
$$
allows to express (1) as an SDE for $X_t$ driven by $B_t\,.$

Comment: Nice approach. A detail: is $F^{-1}$ the generalized inverse or just the inverse? In the latter case we may want $F$ to have an exact inverse.

Comment: @Snoop I think for $f$ to be smooth enough we will need $F$ to have an exact inverse, i.e., be strictly increasing and twice differentiable.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense.